# Google App Script - How to hide columns across muliple sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I created a custom menu in Google sheets that can hides / unhides columns depending on which metrics the person is interested to view.
It's working great but it only works on "active sheet". I would like the script to hide certain columns in a sheet and hide other columns in another sheet.

The custom menu should contain 3 items: 'Karen view', 'Patrick View' and 'View all'

1. Karen view:

- Hide columns 1 and 3 in sheet 1
- Hide columns 4 and 5 in sheet 2

2. Patrick view:

- Hide columns 1, 2 and 4 in sheet 1
- Hide columns 4 and 5 in sheet 2

3. View all:

- Unhide all columns across all the sheets

Below the script I'm currently using:
(I'm a bit confused on how to use getactivespreadsheet along with getactivesheet, that's where I'm stuck)

```
var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
function onOpen() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Hide metrics')
    .addItem('Patrick View', 'hideColumnsP')
    .addItem('Karen View', 'hideColumnsK')
    .addItem('View all', 'showColumns')
    .addToUi();
}
function showColumns() {
  sh.unhideColumn(sh.getRange(1, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()))
}
function hideColumnsK(){
  showColumns()
  sh.hideColumns(1)
  sh.hideColumns(3)
}
function hideColumnsP(){
  showColumns()
  sh.hideColumns(1,2)
  sh.hideColumns(4)
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following modified script?

#### Modified script:

```js
function onOpen() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Hide metrics')
    .addItem('Patrick View', 'hideColumnsP')
    .addItem('Karen View', 'hideColumnsK')
    .addItem('View all', 'showColumns')
    .addToUi();
}

function showColumns() {
  const sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  showColumnsInAllSheets_(sheets);
}

function hideColumnsK() {
  const obj = [{ sheetName: "Sheet1", hide: [1, 3] }, { sheetName: "Sheet2", hide: [4, 5] }];
  sample_(obj);
}

function hideColumnsP() {
  const obj = [{ sheetName: "Sheet1", hide: [1, 2, 4] }, { sheetName: "Sheet2", hide: [4, 5] }];
  sample_(obj);
}

function sample_(obj) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheets = ss.getSheets();
  showColumnsInAllSheets_(sheets);
  const sheetObj = sheets.reduce((o, s) => (o[s.getSheetName()] = s, o), {});
  obj.forEach(({ sheetName, hide }) => {
    if (sheetObj[sheetName]) {
      hide.forEach(h => sheetObj[sheetName].hideColumns(h, 1));
    }
  });
}

function showColumnsInAllSheets_(sheets) {
  sheets.forEach(s => s.showColumns(1, s.getMaxColumns()));
}
```

- In this modification, the specific columns of the specific sheet can be hidden by giving an object for the sheet and column information.
- And also, in this modification, when `showColumns()` is run, all columns of all sheets are shown.
- If you want to change the sheet names and columns, please modify `obj` in the functions `hideColumnsK` and `hideColumnsP`.

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's working!
May I ask a bit more details about the obj function? Not sure to understand what the o, s and h refer to

Comment: @Damien Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About `May I ask a bit more details about the obj function? Not sure to understand what the o, s and h refer to`, in this sample script, `o` and `s` are the object of `{}` and Class Sheet object of `sheets`, respectively. And `h` is the column number from `obj`. If this expanation was not useful, I apologize.