# Hide an array of columns in Google App Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script

Beginner programmer here, apologies in advance if my vocabulary is not really accurate while explaining my issue.

I have a script that creates a custom menu (view) and hides different set of columns based on the view you want to see.

How can I change the script so instead of typing all my columns I can get an array of columns (in this case array [1 to 4] and [7 to 13])?

Below the particular section of my code that I'd like to change

```
function hideColumnsAll30() {
  const obj = [{ sheetName: "Planning / Tracking", hide: [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13 ] }, { sheetName: "Resources", hide: [2, 4, 5, 9]}, {sheetName: "Documentation", hide:[2, 4, 5, 9]} ];
  sample_(obj);
}
```

And here is the full script if it helps solving my issue

```
function onOpen() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Custom View')
    .addItem('All - 30 days', 'hideColumnsAll30')
    .addItem('All - 1 year', 'hideColumnsAll1y')
    .addItem('Unhide All', 'showColumns')
    .addToUi();


function showColumns() {
  const sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  showColumnsInAllSheets_(sheets);
}

function hideColumnsAll30() {
  const obj = [{ sheetName: "Planning / Tracking", hide: [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13 ] }, { sheetName: "Resources", hide: [2, 4, 5, 9]}, {sheetName: "Documentation", hide:[2, 4, 5, 9]} ];
  sample_(obj);
}

function hideColumnsAll1y() {
  const obj = [{ sheetName: "Planning / Tracking", hide: [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, ] }, { sheetName: "Resources", hide: [2, 4, 5, 9]}, {sheetName: "Documentation", hide:[2, 4, 5, 9]} ];
  sample_(obj);
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `How can I change the script so instead of typing all my columns I can get an array of columns (in this case array [1 to 4] and [7 to 13])?`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply!
Right now I need to type all the columns manually -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
I would like to have 2 arrays, like this -> [1 - 4], [7 -13]
But I'm not sure how to change this in my script

Comment: Can you please share an example or copy of your spreadsheet? Would help us understand what you are trying to do so we can help you with your codes and suggest alternatives if any. Screenshots will also help. Or in general you just really want to have these 2 arrays which you can call in your functions?

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Hi, Thank you both for your reply. This is the link to the dummy spreadsheet. You can see a custom menu has been created next to "help", it hides some columns when you click on it.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LC1OHsjsQhQEj9yxeU5ADzvKAsvdpfc9_BVw8NlEFpM/edit#gid=1905203294

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your following replying,

> I need to type all the columns manually -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13] I would like to have 2 arrays, like this -> [1 - 4], [7 -13]

I guessed that you wanted to retrieve an array of `[1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]` by using 2 arrays like `[1 - 4], [7 -13]`. If my understanding is correct, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
const input = [[1, 4], [7, 13]]; // 1st and 2nd element of each array are start and end values, respectively.
const res = input.flatMap(([start, end]) => [...Array(end)].map((_, i) => i + 1).slice(start - 1, end));
console.log(res);
```

- When this script is run, an array of `[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13 ]` is obtained.

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [flatMap()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

### Added:

From your following reply,

> I actually found similar piece of code to add to my script online. However it does not fit my case as I need to give the name of each sheets where I want to hide columns.

And, in your provided script, I found the following message.

> I have other speadsheets with 1000+ columns, so I cannot hide them manually from 1 to 1000. This is the reasons why I'm trying to include several arrays in my script

In this case, is the following script your expected script?

```
const columns = input => input.flatMap(([start, end]) => [...Array(end)].map((_, i) => i + 1).slice(start - 1, end));

function hideColumnsAll30() {
  const obj = [{ sheetName: "Planning / Tracking", hide: columns([[1, 4], [7, 13]]) }, { sheetName: "Resources", hide: [2, 4, 5, 9]}, {sheetName: "Documentation", hide:[2, 4, 5, 9]} ];
  sample_(obj);
}
```

- At `hide: columns([[1, 4], [7, 13]])`, `hide: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13 ]` is created.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I actually found similar piece of code to add to my script online. However it does not fit my case as I need to give the name of each sheets where I want to hide columns. Hi, Thank you both for your reply. This is the link to the dummy spreadsheet. You can see a custom menu has been created next to "help", it hides some columns when you click on it. Here is the link to my spreadsheet, it should help understanding my issue
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LC1OHsjsQhQEj9yxeU5ADzvKAsvdpfc9_BVw8NlEFpM/edit#gid=1905203294

Comment: @Damien Thank you for replying. About `I actually found similar piece of code to add to my script online. However it does not fit my case as I need to give the name of each sheets where I want to hide columns.`, I deeply apologize that my proposed sample script was not useful for your situation. From your reply, I added a sample script that reflected my proposed script. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful again, I apologize again.

Comment: Awesome, that works now. I needed to add a constant in order to call an array.
Thanks again for your time

Comment: @Damien Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: Just quick question (sorry about that). If I want to do this on a bigger scale, can I create several const? For instance: const columns = input => input... const columns2 = input => input.... And then: hide: columns([[1, 4], [7, 13]]), hide: columns2 ([[18, 22], [28, 30]]) ... Would that works?

Comment: @Damien In this case, you are not required to create `columns2`. You can use only `const columns = input => input.flatMap(([start, end]) => [...Array(end)].map((_, i) => i + 1).slice(start - 1, end));`. It's like `hide: columns([[1, 4], [7, 13]])` and `hide: columns([[18, 22], [28, 30]])`. Please put the function of `const columns = ,,,` as the global.

Answer (score 1):

### Suggestion

In your script I am not sure where you will use the arrays 1-4 and 7-13 since  in the scripts specially on the part `{ sheetName: "Planning / Tracking", hide: [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13 ] }` you are skipping number 10 here and on the other function you skipped 2.

Here's a suggestion on how you can use an array to your function. You can just add a new variable outside the functions to make it global variables, here is where you will insert the array values you want. You can then access these variables in any of your functions so you only have to edit one line in case you will adjust the columns.

Try this code:

```
function onOpen() {
 const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Custom View')
    .addItem('All - 30 days', 'hideColumnsAll30')
    .addItem('All - 1 year', 'hideColumnsAll1y')
    .addItem('Unhide All', 'showColumns')
    .addToUi();
};

//Declare arrays here***
//Put in array the columns for Resources and Documentation sheets
var resDocArray = [2,4,5,9];
//Put in array the columns for the planning/tracking tab for 2 different functions
var colAll30d = [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13];
var colAll1y = [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12]
//***

function showColumns() {
  const sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  showColumnsInAllSheets_(sheets);
};

function hideColumnsAll30() {
  const obj = [{ sheetName: "Planning / Tracking", hide: colAll30d }, { sheetName: "Resources", hide: resDocArray}, {sheetName: "Documentation", hide:resDocArray} ];
  sample_(obj);
};

function hideColumnsAll1y() {
  const obj = [{ sheetName: "Planning / Tracking", hide: colAll1y }, { sheetName: "Resources", hide: resDocArray}, {sheetName: "Documentation", hide:resDocArray} ];
  sample_(obj);
};

function sample_(obj) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheets = ss.getSheets();
  showColumnsInAllSheets_(sheets);
  const sheetObj = sheets.reduce((o, s) => (o[s.getSheetName()] = s, o), {});
  obj.forEach(({ sheetName, hide }) => {
    if (sheetObj[sheetName]) {
      hide.forEach(h => sheetObj[sheetName].hideColumns(h, 1));
    }
  });
};

function showColumnsInAllSheets_(sheets) {
  sheets.forEach(s => s.showColumns(1, s.getMaxColumns()));
};
```

You can also add the arrays the way Tanaike suggested.

Let me know if this helps!

Reference:
[Hide columns in multiple sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71907760/)

Comment: Do you have more columns to hide than to retain? As you've mentioned in the dummy file you got other spreadsheets with over 1000+ columns, if there are only few columns to retain perhaps it would be better to select the columns to retain and hide all the other columns? Let me know if this is an alternative that works for you so I can add it in the post.

Comment: Thank you Dan. I think Tanaike solution works better as it includes an array (again I'm very beginner programmer so really not the best one to judge). I guess I could use several const to solve my 1000+ columns issue

Comment: That's great! You can actually use it together with Tanaike's solution so there's only one area where you will look at and edit the arrays, and also you will be able to reuse them in different functions if needed.